# Custom Boolean wrapper in Actionscript

Tags: java, actionscript-3, boolean

I'm in the process of writing a Java Boolean equivalent in Actionscript since Actionscript Boolean does not support `null` so I have to write my custom boolean.

Does any have any idea how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a custom boolean class, you will need to start by constructing that class.

[Here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html) is a link to an Adobe article giving a brief intro on classes.

You will probably want lots of functionality in this class, similar to Java, so look through [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) page to see exactly what the Java Boolean class can do.

I am unsure if ActionScript has anything similar to the Comparable interface that Java Provides, so your conditional statements may require a method call to the Boolean object to return the primitive data, i.e.:

```
    if(myBooleanObject.getValue()){
        doSomeCode();
    }
```

I hope this helps, as you question was slightly vague.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't your best option to create a custom class which extends boolean. Actually, I'm not certain of a circumstance where it is a good idea to extend any primitive, at least in AS.

You're far better off having some other value -- if needs be use one of the number variants and have it set to NaN off the bat. Better yet, use int and a > < = comparator. Even better still, use constants and compare based off of those.